# How can I remove a certain character from a sql database table column?

Tags: sql, database

I want to remove all '#' in the 'defect' column shown below.

Is there a statement which deletes all of them at once?!

Here is an extract of my table, its name is 'defect_table':

```
id  defect  x   y       project

1   #1348   156 2584    5

2   #1366   157 2585    5

3   #1349   158 2586    5

4   #1349   159 2587    5

5   #1349   160 2590    5

6   #1349   161 2591    5

7   #1349   162 2592    5

8   #1349   163 2593    5

9   #1361   164 2588    5

10  #1361   165 2589    5

11  #1361   166 2596    5

12  #1341   167 2595    5

13  #1370   185 2609    5

14  unknown 200 2619    5

16  1497    316 482     5
```

I also want to remove entries which aren't a number at all like 'unknown' at line 14. Maybe there is somebody who can answer both questions at once. :)

Comment: Do you have text other than 'unknown' in your defect column which you want to remove?

Comment: yes, unfortunately I have more then one kind of text in the defect column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update defect_table
  set defect = replace(defect, '#', '')
where defect like '%#%'
```

The `WHERE` clause can be removed if most rows are expected to have an #. (It's there only to keep transaction size down.)

Answer (score 0):

Use update statement mentioned by jarlh above to remove all '#'.
Now execute following delete statement remove all the rows which do not have integer data in your 'defect' column.

```
DELETE FROM defect_table
WHERE defect NOT LIKE '[1-9]'
```

Comment: While it is a good thing to take those records in account, maybe another action would be preferable (such as setting the value to `null`so the type of the field coud be redefined as integer).

Comment: I agree with C.Champagne, If you need those records for future than do not delete them, instead UPDATE 'defect' column with 'NULL' using above WHERE clause. But if do not require them for future, you can perform DELETE operation